# Spring Boot maven plugin - how do I build an executable jar and include a script to run it?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I have a Spring Boot Java application that uses the spring boot starter parent and builds with the spring boot maven plugin. I would like to be able to produce an executable jar file and include a bash script that can be used to run the application. The end result should be a zip file with the jar file and script. The zip should include all dependencies as well.

I've been trying to do this, but have not had any luck with including a script in the end result. Actually, I haven't been able to get it to produce a zip file. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Does the spring boot maven plugin not handle this kind of scenario?

Parentage:

```
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.1</version>
  </parent>
```

Plugin:

```
  <build>

    <finalName>archive-gitlab-project</finalName>

    <plugins>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <mainClass>a.b.c.MainClass</mainClass>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Should I be using something other than the spring boot maven plugin?

Comment: make a separate module; use the maven-assembly-plugin to create tar.gz/zip file which contains the spring boot jar file and the resulting bash script... To include all deps another time does not make sense because they are already included in the resulting jar file (spring boot file)...

Answer (score 0):

> ```xml
> <configuration>
>   <mainClass>/a/b/c/mainClass.class</mainClass>
> </configuration>
> ```

that configuration is wrong, you need to use class name instead of file name, i.e.:

```xml
<configuration>
  <mainClass>a.b.c.mainClass</mainClass>
</configuration>
```

> Does the spring boot maven plugin not handle this kind of scenario?

Actually, `spring-boot-maven-plugin` can do even more: [fully executable applications for Unix systems](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment.html#deployment.installing)

Comment: Do you have an example of how to do this?

Comment: what have you tried and what does not work as expected?

Comment: When I tried an "embedded script", it put my script *inside* the jar file. What good does that do me? How am I supposed to use it? My intent was to package the script *with* the jar file in order to execute it.

Comment: OK, if you think 3 files are better than single one that is your choice, read about `maven-assembly-plugin` as was suggested by @khmarbaise

Comment: What is the point of having the script inside the jar file? How do you invoke it?

Comment: "inside the jar file" - that is your words, not mine. please read documentation first.

Comment: I did, but I don't understand how to use it.

Comment: first step: add `<executable>true</executable>` into plugin configuration - that is mentioned in documentation, do you have an idea how to edit xml files? second step: build project - do you have and idea how to type `mvn clean package` in command line? third step: run resulting jar as standard UNIX application - do you have an idea how to run UNIX applications?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the documentation you refer to? I'm looking at https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/index.html and I can't find the reference to the plugin configuration.

Comment: My A is about capabilities of `spring-boot-maven-plugin` and I had provided corresponding links. Please discuss `maven-assembly-plugin` with @khmarbaise